# property-based-test for simple object validation

Tags: unit-testing, testing, language-agnostic, property-based-testing

consider this simple example:

- Theres a `Person` object
- It must have one of: `FirstName` and `LastName` (or both, but one is mandatory)
- It must have a valid `Age` (integer, between 0 and 150)

How would you property-base-test this simple case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can meaningfully answer this question in a language-agnostic way, as the overall design approach will entirely depend on the capabilities of the language in question.

For example, in languages with strong static types and sum types, most of the above requirements can be modelled declaratively using the type system. Here's an F# example:

```
type Name =
| FirstName of string
| LastName of string
| FullName of string * string
```

This `Name` type can only contain either a first name, or a last name, or both. It's not possible to create values that don't follow the requirements.

The case constructor of the following Age type can be hidden by putting the type in a separate module. If that module only exports the `toAge` (and `getAge`) function below, the only way to create an `Age` value would be to call `toAge`.

```
type Age = Age of int

let toAge x =
    if 0 <= x && x <= 150
    then Some (Age x)
    else None

let getAge (Age x) = x
```

Using these auxiliary types, you can now define a `Person` type:

```
type Person = { Name : Name; Age : Age }
```

Most of the requirements are embedded in the type system. You *can't create an invalid value* of the `Person` type.

The only behaviour that can fail is contained in the `toAge` function, so that's the only behaviour that you can meaningfully subject to property-based testing. Here's an example using FsCheck:

```
open System
open FsCheck
open FsCheck.Xunit
open Swensen.Unquote

[<Property(QuietOnSuccess = true)>]
let ``Value in valid age range can be turned into Age value`` () =
    Prop.forAll (Gen.choose(0, 150) |> Arb.fromGen) (fun i ->
        let actual = toAge i
        test <@ actual |> Option.map getAge |> Option.exists ((=) i) @>)

[<Property(QuietOnSuccess = true)>]
let ``Value in invalid age range can't be turned into Age value`` () =
    let tooLow = Gen.choose(Int32.MinValue, -1)
    let tooHigh = Gen.choose(151, Int32.MaxValue)
    let invalid = Gen.oneof [tooLow; tooHigh] |> Arb.fromGen
    Prop.forAll invalid (fun i ->

        let actual = toAge i

        test <@ actual |> Option.isNone @>)
```

As you can tell, it tests the two cases: valid input values, and invalid input values. It does this by defining generators for each of those cases, and then verifying the `actual` values.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I don't know F# but it seems that you could create an invalid person also passing in empty strings am I correct? I guess in that case you would check their length the same way you checked the age range, right?

Comment: Correct, if empty strings are invalid  (which would be reasonable) then the approach would be the same as for the age.